# "dm-tool lock" doesn't lock my session

Tags: lightdm, login-screen, lock-screen

When I use **dm-tool** to lock the screen for userA, I can log in as userB and then use **dm-tool** to switch back to userA's session without having to enter a password.  Is that the expected behavior?  If not, how should I switch from A to B without leaving userA exposed?

```
userA$ dm-tool lock
```

--> Shows Greeter.  Login as userB.

```
userB$ dm-tool switch-to-user userA
```

--> Expected this to go to greeter, but it goes right back to userA's session.

Do I have something mis-configured, or what?

Comment: I have this problem on 22.10 (lightdm 1.30.0)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried doing that and what I actually had is not exposed, but locked session of user A.

Say I'm logged in @ Vty/7 as user A and then when I do "dm-tool lock" it switches me to another Vty with new instance of X server and login window. But I can skip login into and easily go back to Vty/7 — pressing Ctrl_Alt_F7. When I do this, I see locked user A session, there's no doubt.

Answer (score 0):

As of today it looks like this behaviour pertains to an older version than lightdm 1.18.3.

However on lightdm 1.18.3 I encounter that the screen illumination is switched off after

```
dm-tool switch-to-user userA
```

The computer (in my case a Lenovo T400 running xubuntu 16.04, currently with kernel 4.10.0-32-generic x86_64) is still running after that, I observe the WLAN LED blinking. In this situation I can use Ctl+Alt+F1 to switch to a console (and the screen light goes on!) which opens with a greeter dialog. But I can also immediately use Ctl+Alt+F7 to return to my GUI session which I left.

**It looks to me that there is a bug in dm-tool switch-to-user switching off the screen illumination** (at least on my laptop).

Of course, when I am in the console started witn Ctl+Alt+F1 I can log on as a different user and start a GUI issuing

```
startx
```

But this is definitely not what is advertized for

```
switch-to-user USERNAME [SESSION]
```

> "Switch to a user session.  If this user is already logged in then
>   the display manager will switch to that session, otherwise a new
>   session is started. If authentication is required a greeter 
>   will start to collect this. If the session option is provided then
>   this session type will be used, otherwise the default for this
>   user is used."